# How to force solve_ivp to only allow positive solutions for integrated variables?

Tags: scipy, ode, differential-equations

I am modelling the freezing of ice on a surface over time. This requires calculating the 'rate of freezing/melting', which can be greater or less than zero. **The constraint I want to impose is that if the amount of frozen ice on the surface is zero, and if the rate of freezing is negative, the amount of ice cannot go below zero (physically impossible).**

This is a minimal example of what I am trying to do. You can see the if statement where I try to force the solution value to be >= 0, however this does not work. How do you do this with solve_ivp?

Note: this code does not run, it is just a shell to show what I am looking to do

```
def df(t,x,*system_constants):

    ##setting up derivative array
    dxdt = np.zeros_like(x)

    # [position][diff eq number]
    # Ice solid deposition rate (dMi/dt), solving for total deposited ice
    dxdt[0][0] = x[0][0] * a

    if x[0][0] < 0:
        x[0][0] = 0

    return dxdt

#create your initial conditions
t0 = 0
tf = 10 
t = (0,tf)

#solve the system
sol = solve_ivp(df, t, x0, args = system_constants, method = 'LSODA', dense_output=True)
```